# Magento 2.3 How to create custom cms page url?

Tags: magento2.3, url, cms

I have use Magento 2.3

Question: How to modify custom CMS page URL structure?

For example: I want to this type of page link.
http://mydomainxyz.com/parent-service/childpage

At present we are only able to create this type of url: http://mydomainxyz.com/childpage

So please provide me appropriate solution for this 
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried this? https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-cms-page-rewrites-magento-2.html

Comment: let me check and get back to you

Comment: its working but one problem

Why the URL redirect like this http://mydomainxyz.com/cms/page/view/page_id/80 

Page ID is display in URL

Comment: You can customize your URL what u want.....by the default magento will provide url with page id

Comment: Ok done Your answer is correct

Comment: Please submit your answer with appropriate detail. So i have confirm it and improve rating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the cms page url by using CMS page URL rewrites

Pls refer this link - [Magento 2 CMS page URL rewrite](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-cms-page-rewrites-magento-2.html)

By default Magento provide url with calling controller path with page id by following / in front end by it's page name

```
mydomainxyz.com/cms/page/view/page_id/80
```

We can override whatever we want using CMS Page URL rewrites in `Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites.`